# What would be the best way to generate the json below using a .net web service?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, json, web-services

What would be the best way to generate the json below using a .net web service? I plan to call this though jquery on the front end.

I'm not seeing if I have to piece it together by hand or if there's an object structure in C# I could use that would equate to this when returned.

```
{'Option 1': {'Suboption':2},'Option 2': {'Suboption 2': {'Subsub 1':5, 'Subsub 2':6}}}
```

Right now I have the data formatted like this

```
Id  |   Text    |  ParentId
1     Option1       null
2     SubOption      1
3     Option2       null
4     SubOption2     3
5     SubSub1        4
6     SubSub2        4
```

But I can change the data structure if it would make it easier to generate the json.

EDIT

---

Final solution is loop with string builder to form up the JSON.

Thanks!

Comment: http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/pini_dayan/archive/2009/03/12/convert-objects-to-json-in-c-using-javascriptserializer.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a recursive data structure to support the nesting.

```
public class Item
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public Item SubItem { get; set; }
}

var myObject = new Item
{
    Id = 1, 
    Text = "Some Text",
    SubItem = new Item { Id = 2, Text = "SubItem" }
}

var serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
string json = serializer.Serialize(myObject);
```

Comment: Thanks for the super speedy response, I don't think that will generate what I'm looking for though.

Say I make an array of Parents, it's going to give me something like in the example you linked to.

The JSON I'm looking for doesn't have the variable name prefixing the Text field and the data is nested not side by side.

Comment: I don't really understand your JSON example.  It doesn't bear much resemblance to your source data example, and I don't get why the nesting is there.  The example I gave is a simple one, but you ought to be able to shape it to your needs.

Comment: Thanks for your help.

 I've updated the question so that the table example has data which matches the JSON.

Comment: Ah, I see.  You need a recursive data structure.  I modified my answer.

Comment: Thanks, using the recursive structure I get the JSON below

    {"Id":1,"Text":"Some Text","SubItem":{"Id":2,"Text":"SubItem","SubItem":null}}


What I would want to end up with is 

    {"Some Text": {"Subitem":2}

Does it sound like I just need to loop though my objects and build up the JSON with a stringBuilder?

Comment: It might come to that.  But you could get closer by changing some of the names of the properties.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14086/discussion-between-andrew-walters-and-robert-harvey)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to serialize a tree-like structure, so you need to build a tree of some sort.  You can maybe use something like this:

```
class Node
{
  public String Text {get;set;}
  public Node[] Children {get;set;}
  public int Id {get;set;} // if you still need this
}
```

though it sort of reverses things (links to children instead of to parents).

Also, you can't achieve your exact output with this technique, because the keys are different at every level.  Using a class like I have here means that the JSON keys will always be "Text", "Children" and "Id", but that should be enough.

If that's not what you want, you can always use a Dictionary<String, Object>, whose values are either strings or more dictionaries.